# Slow Boot loading drivers (pre Windows Logo Screen)

Tags: windows-xp, boot, dell-vostro

I have a

- Vostro 1000 laptop
- XP SP3
- 1.5 GB Ram
- Athlon 64 processor

I just reinstalled Windows on the disk, finished adding all the drivers and the critical updates, and now it has a load time over 4 minutes.  Once it's booted, it works very quickly.

I booted in safe mode to watch the driver load list, here are the drivers that seem to be hanging:

- system32\hal.dll
- system32\kdcom.dll
- system32\config\system
- system32\c_1252.nls
- system32\c_437.nls
- system32\l_intl.nls
- AppMatch\drvmain.sdb

Comment: You installed something that is causing it to boot slowly beyond the fact its going to be slow no matter what you do.

Comment: Normally an installed program causes a slow boot from the time the Windows Logo screen appears.  As soon as that screen appears, everything runs very quickly (even post logon).  It's only before that screen that I have a slow load time.